Issues with Go 1.22 http routing and workspaces
I'm experimenting with Go's new net/http routing introduced in 1.22. This is the directory structure:
/foo
  /api
    main.go
    go.mod

api/main.go:
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("GET /{$}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
    })

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: mux,
    }
    err := server.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

api/go.mod:
module example.com/api

go 1.22

Output of go version:
go version go1.22.6 darwin/arm64

When I run the code with cd api && go run main.go and curl http://localhost:8080 I get Hello, World! as expected.
Now, if I create a Go workspace in /foo, the code stops working. I run go work init, which creates a go.work file with:
go 1.22.6

And rerun the code. Now, when I curl http://localhost:8080, I get 404 Not Found. If I now run go work use api/, turning go.work into this:
go 1.22.6

use ./api

The code works again. How can an empty Go workspace file break my code, considering 1.22 is specified everywhere? Am I missing something basic about how Go workspaces work?

How do you know that routing is the problem? I don't know much about workspaces, but perhaps if you don't include "use ./api" then when you build you get the most recent release of that module in source control rather than the local copy?

You can add log.Fatal("bananas") as the first statement in main in api/main.go file, and see if it's executed.

@PaulHankin because if I change "GET /{$}" (new routing) to "/" (old routing) it works as expected, even without the use ./api. Given the new routing was introduced in 1.22, I was assuming the issue to be related to the version of Go somehow.

I can reproduce what you're seeing. I think the problem is GODEBUG defaulting to httpmuxgo121=1 when omit the api module from the workspace. I have run out of time to debug further.... Ref: https://go.dev/doc/godebug

Ah interesting, that you! I wasn't expecting that kind of behaviour. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I can accept it, in case it turns useful for someone else.

My comment isn't an answer yet -- the parts that're missing are: 1. how files run directly from go run (eg: go run api/main.go) are associated with modules when they're in a workspace that doesn't include their directory as a module. And 2. how GODEBUG options are chosen for files that are run directly from "go run".
